# Math's & Excel formula to calculate the interest rate from the EMI and principal amount?

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

**I have 2 Questions**:

[image]

For EMI we have:
Excel Formula: `=PMT(rate, number_of_periods, present_value)`
Maths Fromula: `= P*r*(1+r)^n/((1+r)^n-1)`

**QUESTION 1:** Keeping the principal amount & interest tenure as same, **I want to calculate the interest rate if we change the EMI to 9000.**

For Interest Rate:
Excel Formula: `?`
Maths Fromula: `?`
(Till now, I have used the GOAL SEEK of What If Analysis to achieve the Interest Rate)

**QUESTION 2:**
Recently, I learned about EMI calucations so wanted to tally it with real applications.

So I came across the Apple's website where there are multiple EMI options, so I wanted to get the numbers by myself.The iphone costs **₹1,99,900** and they are giving **₹6000** discount in all credit card payments (whether EMI or one-off both) so in all cases of credit card payments there is at least ₹6000 savings so principal amount gets **1,93,900**.

**For 9 Months:**
[image]
**EMI:** ₹22,913
**Total Amount:** ₹2,06,219
**Savings**: ₹6000

**Our calculations EXACTLY match it:**

[image]

**For 6 Months (NO COST EMI):**
[image]
**EMI:** ₹32,317
**Total Amount:** 1,93,899
**Savings**: ₹6000 + ₹8209

**Our calculations EXACTLY match it:**
[image]

But what doesn't match is the savings they have mentioned, obviously considering the total EMI interest as savings we get ₹8,571 but according to them it is ₹8209. **Can you please explain how did they come up with ₹8209 ?** (using goal seek for ₹8209 interest the principal is ₹1,85,691)

Google Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bQFYfOE7O16lp-sW2DWCibwedszkshuTmOhX2BAqj5Q/edit?usp=sharing